# TFS2015 - How can I recover shelved changes

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Same situation as this [question]: [TFS Meltdown - How can I recover shelved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603522/tfs-meltdown-how-can-i-recover-shelved-changes/23504714#23504714) but for TFS2015.  The issue I'm having is I can't find the files that were added or renamed in my query result.

```
SELECT c.[CreationDate], c.[Content], vi.ChildItem, vi.ParentPath
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Content] c
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_FileMetadata] fm ON fm.ResourceId = c.ResourceId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_FileReference] fr ON fr.ResourceId = fm.ResourceId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_PendingChange] pc ON pc.FileId = fr.FileId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Workspace] w ON w.WorkspaceId = pc.WorkspaceId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Version] vi ON vi.ItemId = pc.ItemId AND vi.VersionTo = 2147483647
WHERE w.WorkspaceName = 'SHELVESET_NAME'
```

**UPDATE:**
Was able to figure out the query.

```
SELECT w.WorkspaceId, c.[CreationDate], c.[Content], pc.TargetChildItem, pc.TargetParentPath
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Content] c
JOIN [dbo].[tbl_FileMetadata] fm ON fm.ResourceId = c.ResourceId
JOIN [dbo].[tbl_FileReference] fr ON fr.ResourceId = fm.ResourceId
JOIN [dbo].[tbl_PendingChange] pc ON pc.FileId = fr.FileId
JOIN [dbo].[tbl_Workspace] w ON w.WorkspaceId = pc.WorkspaceId
WHERE w.WorkspaceName = 'SHELVESET_NAME'
```

Comment: Hopefully this may help someone. I had a similar issue where I lost all my changes to a file I shelved, then checked in a small change (hot fix) to TFS source control, then unshelved to get my original code back (I deleted the shelveset - I didn't think I needed it). I was asked to "Keep unshelved version" or something like "restore original version" when unshelving. I chose restore original version, and found my changes were all gone. To get the original file back, I found a copy of my C# file in this location ( I sorted my date modified descending): C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the query by looking at table tbl_PendingChange and looking for the new files that was added and then correctly updated the original query.